# SP2013 : Alternate Acces Mapping not working on the entirety of the url

Tags: 2013, iis, alternate-access-mapping, https

I am missionned to go from HTTP to HTTPS on our SharePoint 2013 OnPremise farm.

This farm is made of several wfe (4 - including one for Workflows), 2 application servers and 2 sql instances.
Users reach the SharePoint sites through a Proxy created mostly for Load Balancing (HaProxy).

I have installed everything (certificates, bindings, AAMs) as said in article [Configure Alternate Mappings for SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-alternate-access-mappings).

**What is my problem :**

I can reach my sites through https (by typing https://myWebApp.MyDomain.com/sites/MySite ),absolutely no issue there.

When trying to reach my site using http (http://myWebApp.MyDomain.com/sites/MySite), the redirection to https (https://myWebApp.MyDomain.com/sites/MySite/SitePages/Home.aspx) is working well.

When I try to directly access to my homepage via http - Which will be the case of all my user's bookmarks- (http://myWebApp.MyDomain.com/sites/MySite/SitePages/Home.aspx),
The redirection to https does not work and the page is still in http.

Could you please help me resolve this strange case of strange behavior ?
Rephrasing : **Could you help me resolve this issue of partial redirection from http to https please ?**

**What I have done :**

here are my configured AAMs :

```
Internal URL                     |   Zone     |  Public URL for Zone
https://MyWebApp.MyDomain.com    |   Default  |  https://MyWebApp.MyDomain.com
http://MyWebApp.MyDomain.com     |   Default  |  https://MyWebApp.MyDomain.com
https://MyWebApp                 |   Intranet |  https://MyWebApp  
http://MyWebApp                  |   Intranet |  https://MyWebApp
```

Here are my bindings on my WFE1 server,on myWebApp.MyDomain.com :

```
Type    |  Host Name  |  Port  |  IP Address     |  Binding Info
http    |             |  80    |                 |  
https   |             |  443   |   *             |
```

The right certificate is associated to the https binding.
(well, these work, because I can access my Site through typing a https  URL.

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Did you also set the redirection in IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option for you would be to set up the IIS URL Rewrite Module as explained in the article below-
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/02/redirect-http-to-https-in-sharepoint-2013.html

I have been using it in our Production environment and it is working just fine for me.

Comment: I thought this was not mandatory, because SharePoint and AAMs assure this redirection. But because it was not complete, I tried the link you shared and it worked. Thanks ! One more question : do I have to set the IIS Rewrite rule for all my WebApps, INCLUDING workflow management site ? Thx !

Comment: Yes if you want them to get redirected then you will need to do it. If you want to do this in bulk refer to the link below - https://www.imaginet.com/2017/step-step-tutorial-iis-redirectrewrites-sharepoint/ . They have the safest and easiest option on how to do this quickly.